# Can I use an Italian passport that expires in December to Travel to Germany in August?

Tags: passports, eu, italian-citizens

I hope someone can help me. I have an italian passport that will expire in December of this year.  I have a trip planned in August, to go to Germany for 3 days.  Can I use my Italian passport seeings as it only expires in December, or do I need to have 6 months validity remaining to be able to use it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Your passport only has to be valid during your journey, there is no 6 month rule among EU member states.

Even if it was expired, you could travel to Germany with only your CIE card and no passport.